# Calculate mean on groups based upon condition in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame. There is a particular 2 columns of interest in this frame.

Lets call it Score and Group

I want to find the mean of each groups score.
I know I could do like

mean(subset(mydata$Score, mydata$Group > 10 & mydata$group < 20))

That gives me the mean of the rows whose has a group value of between 10 and 20,

Now the problem is, that works fine for that 1 particular subgroup, but I have to apply it to hundreds based upon a slightly more complex conditional
Lets say,  Group can have 1000 different values, so I could do like
mean(subset(mydata$Score, mydata$Group == X))

But X is changing, and I need to save for each one,  whats a good way to do this?

Comment: you want tapply, or by or aggregate or ddply or data.table with by

Comment: You could also look at the Mosaic package; its mostly for teaching, but it adds the nice `mean(Score ~ Group)` syntax.

Answer (score 2):

`aggregate` from base R, as mentioned in the comments, specializes in this type of task

```
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(Score=floor(runif(10, 0, 10)),
                  Group=sample(letters[1:3], 10, rep=T))

aggregate(Score ~ Group, data=dat, mean)
#   Group    Score
# 1     a 4.333333
# 2     b 7.666667
# 3     c 5.500000
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found another solution to my own problem.

```
sapply(1:100, function(x) median(subset(myData$Score, myData$Group == x)))
```

Where in this instance, I am simply having the conditional be `Group == X`,  whereas that can be anything, either a range or multiple conditions

And then also `Score` can be manipulated as well inline there

If someone has a better way to do this, please do add, but I think this meets my current needs.